# What is the path to notepad++ on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, notepad++, filezilla

I am trying to set file associations in filezilla on ubuntu. Seems to be a simple solution on windows but I can't quite figure it out on ubuntu. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Notepad++ on Ubuntu using the unofficial Snap/Wine method, I think the executable is called `notepad-plus-plus`.

Comment: Yup, found it, thank you.
I was trying to set it as the default editor for Filezilla on Ubuntu but cant seem to get the syntax right. It was so simple on my Windblows machine. I'll post a more specific question to that effect. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
which notepad-plus-plus
```

returns:

```
/snap/bin/notepad-plus-plus
```

Answer (score 0):

`which` is your friend.

`which notepad++` should return the path to the notepad++ executable.

Comment: 'which notepad++' and 'which -a notepad++' return nothing :(